# Move App Menu to be with Title Bar

Tags: menu-bar

I'm coming from PC-land (Windows / X (Linux / FreeBSD)).

I would like the "App Menu" (Microsoft Teams Edit View Window Help) to stay with the application window and the Red Yellow Green buttons.  I am on a system with an external monitor and it is awkward to have to go to the primary display to get to a menu option that is on the external display.  In any case, I don't want to move the mouse very far.

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried with the external monitor as the "Main Display"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The menu bar will appear on all displays if you go to System Preferences > Mission Control, and tick the setting "Displays have separate Spaces".

There is no way to customise the interface to put the menubar in a window. Some menus, e.g. "Window", control things relating to more than the current window, and/or the application as a whole.

Also remember that unlike Windows, each document window is not a separate instance of the application: the application process can still be running without any document windows. *(Though apps that can only have one window should quit when that window is closed.)*

Comment: Ok, I have that off so it behaves more like what I'm familiar with.  I was afraid I couldn't change that.  Since Apple is FreeBSD, perhaps I can just boot up to a terminal and start X11 :).

Comment: @JohnDoe X11 is not included with macOS, though there is an implementation for Mac called Xquartz. It would be a lie to say that macOS "is" FreeBSD.

Comment: Ok, I won't debate the semantics of 'lie' as you're welcome to your opinions.  I'm not sure how useful XQuartz would be though, thanks for the information, perhaps it may be useful.